# For $x_{n+1}=\frac{2}{1+x_n}$ and $0\leq x_1\leq 1$, how to show odd terms are increasing, even terms are decreasing, and the sequence converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $0\leq x_1 \leq 1$ and consider the series 
$$
x_{n+1}=\cfrac{2}{1+x_n}.
$$ 
How do I prove that $(x_{2n-1})^\infty_{n=1}$ is and increasing sequence and $(x_{2n})_{n=1}^\infty$ is and decreasing sequence and that $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convergence of the $a_1 = a, a_{n + 1} = \frac{2}{a_n + 1}$ sequences by using subsequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2595894/convergence-of-the-a-1-a-a-n-1-frac2a-n-1-sequences-by-using-s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $f(x) = \frac{2}{1+x}$. Then $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$. Compute the double iteration:
$$g(x) := f^{(2)}(x) = \frac{2}{1+f(x)} = \frac{2}{1+\frac{2}{1+x}} = \frac{2(1+x)}{3+x} = \frac{2+2x}{3+x}.$$

Claim: If $0 \leq x\leq 1$, then $x \leq g(x) \leq 1$.

Proof: $$\frac{2+ 2x}{3+x} = \frac{2 + x + 2}{3+x} \leq \frac{2 + 1 + x}{3 + x} = 1.$$
$$\frac{2+2x}{3+x} \geq \frac{2x + 2x}{3+x} \geq \frac{4x}{3+1} = x.$$

Then $x_1, x_3, ..., x_{2n+1},... = x_1, g(x_1),...,g^{(n)}(x_1),...$ is a bounded increasing sequence, hence convergent. Denote $y_n := g^{(n)}(x_1)$. Then $y_n \to y$ for some $y \in [0,1]$. Then by continuity $g(y_n) \to g(y)$. But $g(y_n) = y_{n+1} \to y$. So $g(y) = y$. Then note that 1 is the unique fixed point of $g(x)$ in $[0,1]$. Hence $y = 1$.

A very similar argument will show that $x_{2n}$ is a decreasing sequence in $[1,\infty)$. Then you will get that $x_{2n} \to 1$ also (using the same fixed point argument). Then you can conclude $x_n \to 1$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: If your question has been resolved, please upvote and accept the answer by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$x_{n+2}={2+2x_n\over 3+x_n}=2-{4\over 3+x_n}$$

If $x_k>1$ for some $k$, then $$x_{k+2}>2-{4\over 3+1}=1$$ also $$
{
x_k^2+x_k>2\implies
\\x_k^2+3x_k>2+2x_k\implies
\\x_k>{2+2x_k\over 3+x_k}\implies
\\x_k>x_{k+2}\implies
1<x_{k+2}<x_k
}
$$
for $0<x_k<1$ we can similarly show that $$x_k<x_{k+2}$$note that since $x_1<1$ and $x_2={2\over 1+x_1}>1$, then the sequences $a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n-1}$ are decreasing and increasing, respectively.

To show that $x_n$ converges, by solving $l={2\over l+1}$, a good candidate for convergence is $1$. Define $$e_n=|x_n-1|$$

hence $$e_{n+1}={e_n\over x_n+1}$$Since $x_1>0$, then $e_{n+1}\to 0$ and the proof is complete.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help!${}$